# Does storing two components of a secret in two places increase safety?

Tags: cryptography, security-theater

Let's say I have a secret integer X, and so I don't risk losing it, I store it encrypted on some cloud service.  But I think there's a small probability that it gets hacked.  So to help allay those fears, I generate a random number R, and store X+R on the cloud, and R on some other cloud service.  It *seems* like I should feel more secure, since a hacker cannot do anything with X+R alone, or R alone.  Is this right?

PS: I guess I have also increased my chance of losing my data (roughly doubled).  But it seems like probability of someone figuring out X has probably decreased by a much greater fraction (1/P) than this doubling.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, storing parts of secrets in multiple locations helps prevent against their unauthorized use.  An attacker would need both parts (in the scheme you describe) to make use of your secret.  As you point out, it also doubles the risk of *you* losing access to your secret.  In the world of the CIA triad (Confidentiality, Integrity, and Availability), you've traded off lower Availability for higher Confidentiality.  If you're comfortable with that ratio, you can stop here.

If you want more control over the ratio of Confidentiality and Availability, then you can use a scheme invented by Adi Shamir (the S in RSA).  [Shamir's Secret Sharing Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing) is essentially "RAID" for secrets.  You store multiple pieces such that some number of pieces is necessary to reconstruct it.  For example, you can "split" the secret into 5 pieces, but in a way that only 3 are necessary to recover the original secret.  Assuming you have enough places to put the keys, this means you'd need *3* failures to lose access to your key, *and* an attacker would need to compromise *3* hosts to gain access to the key.

Answer (score -1):

What you describe is similar to a one time pad. For `n` bytes of data `d`, take `n` bytes of random data `r` and store `r` in one location and `r xor d` in another. Without both `r` and `r xor d` it is provably impossible to get `d` (with the caveat of `r` needing to be truly random, a flaw in your random number generator could make it trivial to break).

Comment: Why the downvote? I don't see anything wrong here.